# Redirecting user to home page on state change (infinite loop error)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, firebase

I am using UI Router and Firebase. Users are redirected to a thank you page after a transaction is complete. After a certain period of time, the session ends, and the user is automatically redirected to the home page.

If a user attempts to navigate away from the thank you page before then (e.g., by clicking the back button), I'd like to automatically redirect the user to the home page. The goal is to then have an unauthenticated, clean app.

When I use the following code, I get a maximum stack size error:

```
.run(['$rootScope', 'Auth', '$state',  function($rootScope, $location, Auth, $state) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState) {

      if (fromState.name === 'thankyou' && toState.name !== 'thankyou') {
        event.preventDefault();
        Auth.$unauth();
        $state.go('home'); 
      }
 })
}])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem

The condition that wraps the `$state.go` line will unconditionally catch itself.

## Example

- We try to navigate away from the *thank you* page toward some unspecified location
- The condition catches us. We're on the *thank you* page, and we're not going to the *thank you* page. Better send us to the *home page*.
- Hey, here we are again, trying to navigate from the *thank you* page to the *home page*. What could go wrong?
- Oh noes! The condition has caught us again. We're on the *thank you* page, but we're going to the *home page*. That isn't the *thank you* page, so we have to the *home page*...
- And the cycle continues forever...

## The Solution

Change the condition to this:

```
if (fromState.name === 'thankyou' && toState.name !== 'home')
```